# Can not boot into TWRP recovery - Black screen

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, twrp, fastboot, xiaomi

I am trying to flash TWRP onto a Redmi Note 4X
I have the device's bootloader unlocked.
I tried the following: Boot into fastboot mode on the Redmi (Vol Down + Power). Then type `fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.2.1-0-mido.img` on my PC. It says

```
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'recovery' (26868 KB)...
OKAY [  0.625s]
writing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.360s]
finished. total time: 0.985s
```

Then press Vol Up + Power. The mi logo appears and then screen turns black and nothing happens.
When I type `adb devices` it says

```
List of devices attached
8dbec68d0604    recovery
```

So it seems I am in recovery but nothing happens.
I tried alternatively with older TWRP versions available for download. Same result. I also tried `fastboot boot twrp-3.2.1-0-mido.img` It says

```
downloading 'boot.img'...
OKAY [  0.617s]
booting...
OKAY [  0.654s]
finished. total time: 1.270s
```

But also same results.
I can restart and load into MIUI just fine after that.

I tried this with the stock MIUI version that came with the phone, also with the latest Stable ROM and also with the latest Developer ROM. Always same result.

When I choose "Reboot into Recovery" from the MIUI Update Settings, I get to the MI-Recovery which seems to work fine.

Now I am out of ideas. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try using USB 2.0 instead of USB 3.0 https://www.xda-developers.com/xiaomi-poco-f1-official-twrp/

Answer (score 1):

I found a thread over at xda that helped me solve the issue:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/redmi-note-4/help/strange-problem-black-screen-redmi-note-t3716706/page10
Apparently it is some issue with a certain kind of display and the official TWRP can't handle it correctly. The proposed solution is to download an unofficial TWRP version found here:
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/9bcY/3AeSnww5N

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem.